# ImageView circular

Tags: android

Como construir uma `ImageView` que seja redonda como a do exemplo abaixo?

[image: ImageView Redonda]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo você pode usar a biblioteca AQuery para adicionar o formato circular a uma imagem, dentre outras coisas legais como o carregamento da imagem, por um loading etc.

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading

Download API: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list

Para adicionar o rounded-corner a um ImageView faça o seguinte:

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);

// Image URL to download
String url = "http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png";

ImageOptions options = new ImageOptions();
options.round = 15;

aq.id(R.id.image).image(url, options);
```

Comment: Gostei muito dessa biblioteca, mas estou usando XML mesmo.

Comment: Ela tem muitos recursos, bastante útil!! :)